# How to track user activity in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails is there a gem which helps to track user activity?

The most obvious way to track/log user activity would be to save all HTTP requests and parameters along with the username into the database. Is there a gem for that?

EDIT:
I would like to track things like:
1) John Smith clicked 'Search' button on the books page
2) Adam Smith viewed the book 'The Wealth of Nations'
etc.

Tracking what actions were performed by what users is essential, so something like google analytics does not really fit the bill.

Thanks

Comment: Please if you downvote add a comment what you think is wrong with the question so I can improve it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get what you need out of using the [Analytical gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/analytical)

Analytical supports numerous services including kissmetrics and clicky, one of which should be an excellent fit for the data you are trying to gather.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no restrictions you should use something like http://www.google.com/analytics/ it is extremely valuable and you can interact with it to customize it to your needs.

Comment: sorry if my question was not clear enough, I need to know what users exactly performed specific actions. Google analytics doesn't track that. Thanks though.

Comment: @user1027996 You can track it also, however you must specify user's name in event. But I don't think it's legal.

Comment: I see, thx. I wonder if it's not legal because I can't give out users' tracking data to third parties by law or smt.